# How to use "find" or "search" function on formula not on values/results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find

I am trying to create an Excel test for begginers but in order to automatically check the answers I plan to put IF/AND function, to check correct result and to check if propper function is used, but using `find` or `search` function doesn't work with formula/function content, only values they produce. For example I would like to know is `sum` function is used on range of numbers, but =find("sum",A1), where A1 is =sum("a1:a10") gives #VALUE! as result.

Is it possible to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FORMULATEXT` function to extract the formula from a cell, then combine it with `FIND` or `SEARCH` functions to find the text.

Adapt the following formula:

```
=FIND("SUM",FORMULATEXT(A3))
```

[image]

```
=FORMULATEXT(A3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know "FORMULATEXT" function even exists.

Comment: @Jovica We all learn new things every day!!! :)